# Assign Mysql show command result to a variable

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, show

How can i assign only table value to a variable as i want to use it in an if condition later on

```
show open tables where `table` = 't1' and in_use >0;
```

Result:

```
Database   table  In_use  name_lock
Ai          t1     1         0
```

Comment: I don't think there's an API for this.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, What i want to do is run analyze on each table, but before that check whether that specific table is in use or not, if its in use then skip analyze nd move to next table

Comment: I think you'll need to do this from a client programming language, not from MySQL.

Comment: Like PHP or Python.

Comment: Im doing it in a stored procedure.. Does that count?

Comment: I don't think so. You can only make a cursor for SELECT queries, not SHOW queries.

Comment: And there doesn't seem to be a metadata table you can query to get this information.

Comment: I think then i'd hve to settle with info column of information_schema.processlist which can tell me if that table is being queried or not

Comment: I didn't realize there was such a table. I only looked in the `mysql` database, I didn't think it would be in `information_schema`

Comment: But that table doesn't have anything about the tables that a process is using, unless you want to parse the query in `INFO`.

Comment: Yeah seems like parsing is the only way right now

Comment: Good luck with that, MySQL string functions are not really up to that task. I guess you could just check whether the table name appears anywhere in INFO.

Comment: But there can be false positives if one table name is a substring of another. E.g. if `foo_bar` is being queries, and you want to know if it's safe to analyze `foo`.

Comment: There's also the general TOCTOU problem.

Comment: Foo_bar problem can be managed by searching the exact table name and TOCTOU problem  shouldn't be a big problem in this case coz main aim is to skip analyze on tables on which lock is acquired for a long duration

Comment: show open tables where `table` = 't1' and in_use >0 into @var, @var2, @var3, @var4; shouldn't this do the trick?

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-open-tables.html) doesn't mention allowing `INTO` in the `SHOW OPEN TABLES` statement.